# long tables manipulating - latex

Tags: latex, longtable

I am writing LaTeX code to generate a long table using longtable package and I want the first column color to be gray

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}

\begin{longtable}[H]{|
>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} |}
\hline
foo & bar \\ \hline 
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable} 

Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.
\end{document}
```

The problem with the produced table is that horizontal lines doesn't appear in the colored area.
Here is my output:
[image]

Any help?

Comment: Please have a look at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf If you want professional looking tables, don't use vertical lines or coloured backgrounds.

Comment: ... that being said, try another pdf viewer, your example works fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/RET4l.png